# Is "out of … reasons" as fine as because of, due to, for?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage

### Examples

Take sentences like:

> **Because of** her alcohol addiction, she spends an extra $20 on booze every day.
>
> **Due to** her alcohol addiction, she spends an extra $20 on booze every day.
>
> **If it wasn't for** her alcohol addiction, she wouldn't spend an extra $20 a day on booze.
>
> **Out of** her alcohol addiction, she spends an extra $20 a day on booze.

I think all four are correct.

Moreover, I think the following is correct:

> **For** therapeutical **reasons**, she spends an extra $20 a day.

What about the following?

> **Out of** therapeutical **reasons**, she spends an extra $20 a day.

### Question

Is *out of … reasons* an acceptable phrase?

If so, is it equivalent to other expressions of causality (because of, due to, for … reasons)?

Semantically? Stylistically?

---

Related but different questions:
[Because of a reason vs for a reason](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314988/because-of-a-reason-vs-for-a-reason)
[Can “due to” and “because of ” be used interchangeably?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably)

Comment: "Out of" doesn't make sense here. You _could_ say "Out of her weekly income of X dollars, she spends Y dollars on booze". (NB _Booze_ is quite a slang term, so it depends on the context of your sentence whether it's appropriate or not.)

Comment: You might be thinking of the phrase "out of concern for ..."

Comment: When using figures and the $ sign to write money amounts, you should place the dollar sign before the figures, with no space,  like this: $20.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHarvey. I see you have professional experience. Do you, perhaps, know any reasons for this rule (be it only custom)? And is it the same for other currencies, especially €?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [good page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol#List_of_currency_symbols_currently_in_use) about currency symbols.

Comment: In English, almost all currency symbols go before the amount. The Euro is the major exception. In non-English speaking countries it usually goes after the amount, and in English speaking countries it usually goes before the amount, however, neither style is mandatory and it is left up to the writer or editor to decide.

Comment: Thanks @CJDennis. I was interested how it is in [Euro English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euro_English). Well, the [Commission's Style Guide](http://publications.europa.eu/code/en/en-370303.htm#position) – which follows BrE – recommends: The euro sign is followed by the amount without space: a sum of €30. NB: The same rule applies in Dutch, Irish and Maltese. In all other official EU languages the order is reversed; the amount is followed by a hard space and the euro sign: une somme de 30 €

Answer (score 1):

No, "out of" is not idiomatically used in the ways you show.

The closest I can think of is the phrase "out of concern for", as in:

> Out of concern for her alcohol addiction, we didn't serve wine when we invited her to dinner.

This is used when describing an action taken to avoid harming someone else.